# Appearance of the spinner

Tags: java, android

i would like my spinner to be as in the picture.i can do it if i follow the android.developers example,but in my app,its necessary to get the spinner items from the java file and not from the strings.xml.this is my code(my code creates a spinner as in the photo but there is radiobutton when the spinner is closed,next to the first spinner item.i want this radio to disappear)

```
array_spinner=new String[4];
array_spinner[0]="a";
array_spinner[1]="b";
array_spinner[2]="c";
array_spinner[3]="d";

Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

WHEN THE SPINNER IS OPEN:

now:

[image]

I would like to be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one looks like an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

[image]

*Edit:*

Okay, after a short research I found some spinner examples in the API examples. They look like this:

[image]

You can find the [code here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Spinner1.html)